# Filtering a graph with a specific camp

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put a filter in my graph.

[Table's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaSha.png)

```
plt.plot(figsize=(20, 10))
tb_final['Price'].loc['2018-01-01':].plot(label='Price')
tb_final['MA10'].loc['2018-01-01':].plot(label='MA10')
tb_final['MA50'].loc['2018-01-01':].plot(label='MA50')
plt.legend()
```

How can I filter my graph with only one of the Symbols, for example, plot the data of symbol 'JSLG3.SA'?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider taking `loc` first and then selecting the columns:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
tb_final.loc['2018-01-01':][['Price', 'MA10', 'MA50']].plot(ax=ax)
```

`ax.legend` is unnecessary because `pd.DataFrame.plot` created appropriate labels for you. For filtering use a binary filter:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
tb_final[tb_final['Symbol'] == 'JSLG3.SA'].loc['2018-01-01':][['Price', 'MA10', 'MA50']].plot(ax=ax)
```

If you want to generate more plots for each of the classes you can `groubpy` Symbol and `apply` a function that takes a dataframe, plots and saves the plot on disk.

Comment: for some reason the code is producing something strange... 
`fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
tb_final[tb_final['Symbols'] == 'JSLG3.SA'].loc['2018-01-01':][['Price', 'MA10', 'MA50']].plot(ax=ax) `
it don't give me a graph with the three respectives lines: 'price', 'MA10' and 'MA50'.

Comment: I did it thank you very much.